# How to Chain Jquery promises

Tags: jquery, promise

I'm using the below code to Check if some data is in my Database already, I then want to pass the new array of data (whats not in my DB) to the next page.  It appears my promises resolve before all the queries complete...

any ideas?

```
         CheckInDB()
                .then(
                    function () {
                        SetupStep3();
                    });

        function CheckInDB() {

            var q = $.Deferred();

            NewsReleasesToAdd = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("NewsReleasesToAdd"));

            $(NewsReleasesToAdd).each(function (i, item) {
                DoCheck(item);
            });
            q.resolve();
            return q.promise();
        }

    function DoCheck(item) {

        var q = $.Deferred();

        var file = '/api/newsreleases/?action=Find&Limit=0&find=' + item.url;
        GetGenericJSONData(file, function (data) {
            if (data.length == 0) {
                NewsReleases.push(item);
            }
            q.resolve();
        });
        return q.promise();
    }

function GetGenericJSONData(url, callbackFunction) {

    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        return callbackFunction(data);
    }).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var responseText = jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
        alert(responseText);
    });
}
function SetupStep3() {
    $("#statusupdate").text(NewsReleases.length + " Database rows loaded - Continue to Step 3.");
    $("#statusupdate").attr("href", "/collaboration/views/admin/newsreleases?step=3")
    window.localStorage.setItem("NewsReleases", JSON.stringify(NewsReleases));
}
```

Comment: `It appears my promises resolve before all the queries complete...` - of course they do ... you don't do anything with the promise returned from `DoCheck(item);` in your `$(NewsReleasesToAdd).each` so `q.resolve();` in `CheckInDB` resolves immediately - promises don't wait for you - I would suggests reading up on [$.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

Comment: in the mean time - https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/rn6ph2ms/ or https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/rn6ph2ms/1/ will probably do what you want

Comment: Both those examples throw errors..I'm using jquery 1.11.3 
I'm attempting to look into .when

Comment: what errors? they were speculations at best by the way :p oh, jQuery 1.11.3 ... hmmm, maybe $.ajax didn't return a promise way back then

Comment: var promises = Array.map.call($(NewsReleasesToAdd), function(item) { 
returns this error            '0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference'

Comment: hot damn ... `Array.prototype.map.call` :p or `[].map.call` - my bad

Comment: so the first fiddle is now https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/rn6ph2ms/2/ ... what was wrong with https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/rn6ph2ms/1/ ?

Comment: That was it. I'm working with this new code and will let you know how I fair.  I've never used this type of code.  Thank you.